value does not fall within the expected range. certificate.GetCertHash()
I want to create a site with a certificate I use this to generate a certificate:
static byte[] MakeCert()
  {
      var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(); // generate asymmetric key pair            
      var req = new CertificateRequest("cn=foobar", ecdsa, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256);
      var cert = req.CreateSelfSigned(DateTimeOffset.Now, DateTimeOffset.Now.AddYears(20));

      //// Create PFX (PKCS #12) with private key
      File.WriteAllBytes($"{path}\\mycert.pfx", cert.Export(X509ContentType.Pfx, "123456"));
      return cert.Export(X509ContentType.Cert);      
  }

Then I call here:
..
    var certBytes = MakeCert();
    store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certBytes, (string)null,
        X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable | X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet);
    store.Add(certificate);
    web.CommitChanges();                                                                        
    var site = web.Sites.Add(appName, "http", $"*:{webPort}:{appName}", appDir);
    site.ServerAutoStart = true;
    var binding = site.Bindings.Add($"*:{sslPort}:{appName}", certificate.GetCertHash(), store.Name);
    binding.Protocol = "https";                                        
    site.ApplicationDefaults.ApplicationPoolName = appPoolName;
    web.CommitChanges();
    store.Close();
    store.Dispose();
    return true;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"An error occurred when creating IIS App: {ex.Message}", "Error");
    return false;
}

But I get the error:

value does not fall within the expected range.

How to correct this?
EDIT: Based on a stackoverflow post after store.Add(certificate); I added a command line execute for solving error:

A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been
terminated.

using this command:

C:\windows.system32\certutil.exe -repairstore {storeName} {CertIdList}

where storeName is store.Name and CertIdList is certificate.SerialNumber the command executes normally except that at the end it request a "smart card", again in another post its is said that:
You should generate your CSR (Certificate Signing Request) through IIS
 > Server Certificates > Create Certificate Request.

So how to make this command completly work?

The error "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated." often indicates an issue with the way the certificate is being stored or accessed in the Windows certificate store. This problem is sometimes related to how the private key is associated with the certificate. You need to ensure the certificate is generated and stored correctly. And the private key is correctly associated with the certificate.
